# How to pass more than one variable to command in loop?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I am trying to do an iterative loop with a skopeo copy. I have tried:

```
  export image_name=$(sed -e 's/\-[^*]*$//' "$line");  
  export version=$(sed -e 's/[^0-9.]*//' "$line" | sed 's/.tar//');

  IFS=$'\n'
  for line in "$(cat list_files.txt)"; do 
    skopeo copy \
    docker-archive:/opt/app-root/src/"$line" \
    docker://private/dsop/test/"$image_name":"$version" \
    --dest-creds="$USERNAME":"$PASSWORD" \
    --dest-tls-verify=false
  done
```

My variables are rightly placed, but it doesn't seem to hand it off properly to my command. Can anyone point out my problem?

Comment: You first 2 lines cannot be outside of the loop, they have no visibility of the $line variable

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the proper way to iterate over the lines of a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are evaluating the variables just once, before the loop. I'm guessing you want

```sh
while read -r line; do
    image_name=$(sed -e 's/-[^*]*$//' <<<"$line")
    version=$(sed -e 's/[^0-9.]*//;s/\.tar$//' <<<"$line")
    skopeo copy \
    docker-archive:/opt/app-root/src/"$line" \
    docker://private/dsop/test/"$image_name":"$version" \
    --dest-creds="$USERNAME":"$PASSWORD" \
    --dest-tls-verify=false
  done <  list_files.txt
```

There is no need to `export` variables unless they need to be visible to a subprocess (such as, here, `skopeo` - but since you pass these values as variables, I'm guessing it doesn't look for and use variables with these names); and `sed -e script x` uses `x` as the input file name, not as the *string* to process. The dash character is just a normal character, and doesn't need to be backslash-escaped in `sed`. Finally, [don't read files with `for`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

The `<<<` "here string" syntax is a Bash extension (which is also available in some other shells, but not portable to POSIX/Bourne `sh`).

Answer (score 0):

At the time you are setting the variables with the `sed` command, the `$line` variable does not exist. You should change it to:

```
  IFS=$'\n'
  for line in "$(cat list_files.txt)"; do 
    image_name=$(sed -e 's/\-[^*]*$//' "$line");  
    version=$(sed -e 's/[^0-9.]*//' "$line" | sed 's/.tar//');
    skopeo copy \
    docker-archive:/opt/app-root/src/"$line" \
    docker://private/dsop/test/"$image_name":"$version" \
    --dest-creds="$USERNAME":"$PASSWORD" \
    --dest-tls-verify=false
  done
```

Comment: This still fails to fix several of the remaining bugs, though without access to the input file, we can only speculate about what the code is really supposed to do.